# Eloquent belongsToMany returns empty json?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

So, Iam trying to make a conversation/message system.
So I have a problem right now. When I use the following line, I get [] (Empty Json):

```
$this->auth->user()->conversations
```

User model:

```
public function conversations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Conversation\Conversation::class);
}
```

But if I use this line, I get data that I want:

```
$this->auth->user()->messages()->first()->conversation->messages
```

Also when a line like the following one is used, I get an error

**Property [conversation] does not exist on this collection instance.**

```
$this->auth->user()->messages->conversation->messages
```

Here are Messages model line:

```
public function conversation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Conversation\Conversation::class);
}
```

Here are User model line:

```
public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Conversation\Messages::class);
}
```

Here are My database schema:
[image: MySQL Database Schema]

So my question is, do I do something wrong here or this is just some kind of bug? Thanks for any answers/help.

Comment: have you tried to `$this->auth->user()->conversations()` - notice the `()`. it means  you call the magic navigation method. while `$this->auth->user()->conversations` will work, it require you to load the conversation first, like `$this->auth->user()->load('conversations')->conversations` i suppose.

Comment: this->auth->user()->load('conversations')->messages gets only a last message by a user. EDIT: Also ignores conversation_id, shows a message from any conversation

Comment: try $this->auth->user()->with('conversations')->get();

Comment: public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Conversation\Messages::class)->load('conversations');
} .   basically use eager loading when you define your relationships.  Now whenever you do return user->load('messages');   converstaitons will be attached to messages